# Best database design when you have attributes that might have attributes of their own?

Tags: xml, database-design

I'm trying to create a database design based on some an XML script. I was wondering what I should do to store the XML tags. The part I really can't understand is how to associate each attribute of a specific database object with its tag?

Comment: Have an attributes table

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to to search on these tags/attributes in the database, or just store them?

If you don't need to do the search, you might just as well store the XML directly in BLOB.

Otherwise, you'l need to "recreate" the hierarchical XML structure in the database. At the most basic level, you'll have a tag and attribute tables, with tags being able to contain other tags, for example:

[image]